# CUDA debugger for windows 7 and VS 2008e

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I was wondering if there is a good cuda debugger for VS 2008 in windows 7. I heard about Nsight but people tell me it is not reliable.

Moreover, how to configure auto complete for cuda in vs 2008. I have syntax highlighting, but no autocomplete

Comment: I think Parallel Nsight deserves an opportunity. _View GPU memory directly using the standard Memory windows in Visual Studio_ sounds amazing :).

Answer (score 3):

Parallel Nsight is the only debugger plug-in available for Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 at the moment. The latest release is Nsight 2.0 and it is a lot more stable than the previous releases.

Comment: what abt auto completion for vs